# Deleting points of a certain value in a line plot in R

Tags: r, plot, line

I'm currently using R to create a line graph. My data frame that I'm using looks similar to:

```
       1989  1990  1991  1992  1993
    A  -30   -16     0     0     0
    B   12    32     7     0     0
    C    0     0     0     0     0
    D    0     3    -8    -6     6
    E    0     0     0     0    -7
```

Each letter is a separate line, the years are on the x axis and then the values are the y axis. I would like a line to only be present if the value does not equal zero. I have no problem plotting the points with the zeros, but I tried to change 0 to NA and that did not work as I anticipated.

How would I go about plotting the data for 0s not to be present in the graph?

Comment: What "did not work as anticipated" really mean? Do you want segments rather than "lines".

Comment: When I changed 0s to NA the graph did not plot as it should have. The x axis went to 1, the y axis disappeared and the lines were no longer drawn correctly.

Comment: @Judy, it'll save a LOT of trouble with the questions if you just paste your code. It'll help people to start from where you've an issue rather than starting from the scratch.

Comment: What does "as it should have" actually mean? You need to say what you want rather than what you don't want.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using `ggplot2`. But first you'll have to *reshape* your data. I'd do this using `reshape2` package as follows:

```
require(reshape2)
# melt the data.frame.. and I've manually added the row names as separate col
dd <- transform(melt(df), grp = LETTERS[1:5])
# change type and replace 0 with NA
dd$variable <- as.numeric(as.character(dd$variable))
dd$value[dd$value == 0] <- NA

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dd, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=grp, colour=grp)) + 
       geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This feels kind of hackish but works for your sample data:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(.5,5.5), ylim=c(min(df)-1,max(df)+1),
         xaxt="n", xlab="Year", ylab="Value")
axis(1,1:5,labels=gsub("X","",names(df)))
apply(df,1,function(x) if(sum(!x==0)>0) points((1:ncol(df))[!x==0],x[!x==0],type="b") )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another variation, using `matplot`, assuming the use of `df` at the end of this post. I changed one of the years to `1997` from `1993` just to show that the x-axis values are interpreted as numerics and not equally spaced factors.

```
df[df==0] <- NA
matplot(as.numeric(names(df)),t(as.matrix(df)), type="o",pch=19,lty=1,ann=FALSE)
title(xlab="Years",ylab="Values")
```

Giving:

[image]

And the data used:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("
       1989  1990  1991  1992  1997
    A  -30   -16     0     0     0
    B   12    32     7     0     0
    C    0     0     0     0     0
    D    0     3    -8    -6     6
    E    0     0     0     0    -7
"),header=T,check.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Arun's answer, I would suggest that if you would like to take away the rows where all entries are 0, you use something like

```
df[sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) !all(df[i,] == 0)),]
```

where `df` is your data.frame. That will get rid of all rows where all elements are 0 and you can plot the rest as you wish.

Comment: emaster70, maybe it's not clear yet. But the question doesn't explictly say anything about not plotting when all values for the row is 0. It just says "do not plot 0" (afaiu)

Comment: @Arun, I guess I understood "I would like a line to only be present if the value does not equal zero" as "If all points of the row are zero,, do not draw a line". The op could certainly have been clearer about his intentions, but thanks for pointing out the ambiguity :)